# Get Google maps to return list of places

Tags: c#, google-maps

I got this code for finding the GeoCode for a town:

```
 public ActionResult GoogleGeoCode(string adr)
        {

            string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=";

            dynamic googleResults = new Uri(url + adr).GetDynamicJsonObject();

            var cordinates = new List<double>();

            var longlat = new LongLatModel();
            var locations = new List<LongLatModel>();


             foreach (var result in googleResults.results)
             {
                 longlat.Latitude = result.geometry.location.lat;
                 longlat.Longitude = result.geometry.location.lng;

             }

             return Json(longlat, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Lets say I would like to create a list of all mueseums in this specific town. I could create a class like this:

```
public class Museum
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
    }
```

This is where i am stuck. How can I make code that adds `"Museum"` to the searchstring to google maps? I guess that if I could do that, I could later make a foreach and create a new Museum in each loop. Any pointers appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You want to search on Latitude and Longitude or do you want to populate your museum object with results found from the address like in your first bit of code?

Comment: Thank you!
Well, the ideal for me would be if I could use the town I pass as a parameter in the above method. If its possible. I dnt really know how it works but maybe i could do something like town + "museum" and somehow get a list back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

I would read through this documentation which may require you get an API key. Looks like this will allow you to search using key words such as city and museum.

Comment: This seems like the way to go! Thank you!

Comment: Link is down, does someone have a updated link